# Can't verify Moq method call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

There is a problem with verifying TextWriter Write method call, with given params. I have this verification code:

```
_htmlHelperMock.TextWritterMock.Verify(x => x.Write(It.Is<IHtmlString>(p => p == MvcHtmlString.Create("</div>"))), Times.Once);
```

which throws this exception:

```
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.Write(It.Is<IHtmlString>(p => p == MvcHtmlString.Create("</div>")))  
No setups configured.

Performed invocations:  
TextWriter.Write(<div class="control-group">)  
TextWriter.Write(</div>)
```

It is interesting that in exception I see the real invocation with strings I want to check. 
How should I configure verify method to check params?

Comment: @marc_s, sorry, but your edit erased some necessary info, I have to revert your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are verifying with `It.Is<IHtmlString>(p => p == MvcHtmlString.Create("</div>"))` (without my understanding of `MvcHtmlString`, it's clear already this will fail). Whatever you invoked during the test will be a different object returned by `Create`. In this `Verify` it is comparing two instances with `==`. These will be object reference equality.

You probably want a `Func<IHtmlString,bool>` which compares the value, not the instance. Are you able to compare a `p.ToString()` (or `ToHtmlString()`) to simply the string `"</div>"`? The `Create` seems like extra work.

`It.Is<T>` takes a function that says "Given a recorded object of type `T`, verify something about that object". So, this expands to (conceptually):

```
IHtmlString actual = theRecordedParameter;
IHtmlString expected = MvcHtmlString.Create("</div>");
bool pass = actual == expected;
Assert.IsTrue(pass);
```

By using some intermediate operations, you can operate on two distinct objects actual and expected, and compare some derived values.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me to fix the issue. It is enough compare p.ToString() with given string and it is work.  _htmlHelperMock.TextWritterMock.Verify(x => x.Write(It.Is<IHtmlString>(p => p.ToString() == "</div>")), Times.Once);

Comment: msi, glad you got it going.